# Server returned HTTP response code: 400

Tags: java

I am reading data from a webservice. The issue if I put the link on the browser it works fine. When I run like this give me error. I am suspecting is it due to the way how I send my parameters. My paramater list has this `dID=1,5,7,11,14,18,26&FromDate=18 Sep 2012 00:00 am&ToDate=18 Sep 2012 10:00 am`. Do I need to do some encoding here?

```
URL xmlURLDM = new URL(urlDM);
InputStream xml2 = xmlURLDM.openStream();
```

I get this error

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: 
 at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1612)
        at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1035)
        at xmlreader.main(xmlreader.java:172)
```

Comment: What's `urlDM` supposed to be?

Comment: It is a an url string. e.g. http://url....?dID=1,5,7,11,14,18,26&FromDate=18 Sep 2012 00:00 am&ToDate=18 Sep 2012 10:00 am

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You do need encoding, most likley it is the spaces in your URL that is causing the trouble.
Use Javas built in url-encoding.  eg:

```
String encoded = URLEncoder.encode(myUrl, "UTF-8");
```

...
    call web service with encoded as URL

There can be other reasons for the status code being 400, but this encoding issue is probably your first stumbling block.

Comment: If I do the whole url I get error so I just do on the FromDate and ToDate values and then join it back to original string and send as url is that right to do ?

Comment: I get this error if I put the whole url java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol:.

Answer (score 1):

The Documentation of URL [says](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html),

> The URL class does not itself encode or decode any URL components
>   according to the escaping mechanism defined in RFC2396. It is the
>   responsibility of the caller to encode any fields, which need to be
>   escaped prior to calling URL, and also to decode any escaped fields,
>   that are returned from URL. Furthermore, because URL has no knowledge
>   of URL escaping, it does not recognise equivalence between the encoded
>   or decoded form of the same URL.

So please use `URLEncoder.encode()` before you invoke `URL()`